# Is it always possible to draw a triangle with its lengths equal to the Non Euclidean norm of vectors $\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf {v-u}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

An inner product on a vector space $V$ assigns to vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ a real number $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})$, such that

(1) $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u}) \geq 0$ for all $\mathbf{u}$, and $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u})=0$ if and only if $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$

(2) $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})=(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u})$ for all $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} ;$

(3) $(\mathbf{u}, a \mathbf{v}+b \mathbf{w})=a(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})+b(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{w})$ for all $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$

(4)Norm of a vector  $\mathbf u$ is  $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u})$ ,

**Example** : Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathbf{u}=\left[\begin{array}{l}u_{1} \\ u_{2}\end{array}\right], \mathbf{v}=\left[\begin{array}{l}v_{1} \\ v_{2}\end{array}\right] .$ Define
$(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})=2 u_{1} v_{1}-u_{1} v_{2}-v_{1} u_{2}+u_{2} v_{2}$

This is an inner product with strange norm for its vectors.

Is it always possible to draw a triangle with its lengths equal to the norms of $\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf {v-u}$ no matter how contrived the inner product and hence the norm is?

Comment: This question isn't clear to me. The line segments formed by the vectors $u$ and $v$ with line segment corresponding to $u-v$ starting at $v$ (or $v-u$ starting at $u$) forms a triangle, so this question seems almost trivially true (assuming $u$ and $v$ are not colinear).

Comment: Have you heard of the triangle inequality?  This question is asking about it.

Comment: @Cameron Williams, I've added more. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ohhhh. You don't mean just the usual Euclidean inner product. That changes things.

Comment: Yes Dear :) . .

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I have added more detail. I'd be glad if you had a look. :)

Comment: Any norm induced by inner product is in fact a norm.

Comment: I couldn't understand that.

Comment: Be careful with the case $\vec u = \vec v$

Comment: IIRC there's a corollary to the triangle inequality that given 3 numbers satisfying the triangle inequality, there is a triangle with side lengths equal to those 3 sides (requires cyclic permutations).

Comment: If $\vec u \neq \vec v$, the triangle inequality comes from the definition of a norm. In addition, if you consider @rubikscube09's comment, I think you get your answer.

Comment: @Arnaldo, Sorry for the delay,so the norm is defined such that the triangle inequality follows?

Comment: @Kashmiri, yes. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics).

Comment: In particular if you have an inner product on a set, that inner product induces a norm, and a proof that the induced norm is indeed a norm involves proving triangle inequality through Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.